# JavaFX MediaPlayer stops when file isn't complete

Tags: java, javafx, media-player

I have a `MediaPlayer` and when there is a file that it is trying to play that isn't fully downloaded, it just stops. There is no indication that it has stopped either, just that there is no more audio. I have tried outputing the status of the `MediaPlayer` with a `ChangeListener`, but the status doesn't change when it stops. Any ideas on how to detect this event? I assume this is easy enough to understand without code :).

I think this also might happen if trying to play a download**ing** file, not sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The darn `MediaPlayer` was being garbage collected. I was so sure it wasn't because it was a field, come to find that the entire program was being garbage collected. Stupid me.

I highly recommend, anybody else that has stopping problems with `MediaPlayer`, check thoroughly for garbage collection.

Comment: I had the same problem. After i read this i made a class variable referencing MediaPlayer and it all worked perfectly afterwards.